# Genus of trancendental curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, rational-functions, transcendental-equations, parametrization

I understand that an algebraic curve is genus 0 iff it can be parameterized using rational functions.  I am curious if there is a simple way to know if a transcendental curve is genus 0?  Specifically the curve: 
$$ 1-e^y-e^xe^{-y}=0 $$
Which can be parameterized as:
$$ y=log(t+1/2), \hspace{10pt} x=log((t+1/2)(1/2-t)) $$

It seems to be genus 0, in that the $\:t\:$ parameter is defined on the Riemann sphere, except at $\:t=\pm \large\frac12$ (the natural logarithm singularity).

Is the above curve genus 0?

Comment: The curve is not algebraic! You are defining it in terms of the exponential function, which is transcendental. Algebraic curves are those define by the zero sets of polynomials.

Comment: Let me edit the question then, to better get at what I am asking.

Comment: What you have written is not even a compact surface, so it doesn't seem to make sense to talk about genus.

Comment: @user4571 It is a non-compact smooth surface by the inverse function theorem. It make's perfect sense to talk about the genus of a non-compact smooth surface (call it half of the of rank $H_1$ if you don't know another definition).